# How to write "group by" + "sum" in just one clause?

Tags: c#, linq, sum, aggregate

I've got sample data of

```
IEnumerable<Employee> ie;
```

Where Employee contains "Name, Salary, Department_id"

I can use 2 clauses to group by Department id and them "Sum" every group in a for loop, like below:

```
        var group3 = ie.GroupBy(x => x.Department_id);
        foreach (var g in group3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(g.Sum(x=>x.Salary));
        }
```

Yes it works, but can I get my code simpler, I mean how can I get rid of the foreach loop to calculate my Sum() just in my linq statement and write it like:

```
var group3 = from e in ie group e by e.Department_id xxxxxxxxx Sum xxxxx
```

How to write this statement? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var results =  ie.GroupBy(x => x.Department_id).Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.Salary));

 foreach (var item in result)
 {
     Console.WriteLine(result);
 }
```

OR

```
ie.GroupBy(x => x.Department_id).Select(g => g.Sum(x => x.Salary))
            .ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```